# How to protect sudosh logs against deletion?

Tags: linux, security, permissions, sudosh

I'm using sudosh to ensure, among other things, that vendors who are given ssh access to my server can be held accountable for operations they perform on the server.

sudosh is recording the logs very well, but it saves the logs with write permissions for the user who is being recorded.

How can I prevent these logs from being deleted by that user?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented something better than sudosh.
Linux offers a way to do this, using the “Audit” system. With this piece of the kernel and its user space tools, you can log the system calls invoked (and other things too).
The most important one to observe is the “execve” system call. Having a record of its invocations, you’ll know what the users are doing after “sudo some_shell”.
See here for more detail.
[Auditing user actions after sudo](http://www.woitasen.com.ar/2011/11/auditing-user-actions-after-sudo/)
This solution with Syslog works perfect for what you want.

Comment: diegows, added some detaail in case the link broke and to help this site.

Comment: It broke: http://web.archive.org/web/20190326155402/https://www.woitasen.com.ar/2011/11/auditing-user-actions-after-sudo/

Answer (score 0):

If you really *have* to give ssh access to "outside" persons, send the log lines as soon as they are generated to a different server of yours they cannot access (syslogd-* is already prepared for **logging to a remote host**).

If a even higher level of security/traceability is needed - **log to a line printer**. They tend "flush" data to paper trail with each carriage return. Let cron write some lines at certain intervals, too (so you can see/document your security is still up and running).